# Action sheet does not work in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift3, ios10, uialertcontroller

I am trying to implement the Action sheet in Swift. Below is the code to implement it. When i execute the code, Xcode does not show any errors and the action sheet does not appear in the simulator. Any help in resolving the issue is much appreciated.

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

```
    func showActionSheet(sender: AnyObject) {

    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Choose an option!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    //Create and add the Cancel action
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
        //Just dismiss the action sheet
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Your example has some formatting issues, and its difficult to tell what exactly you are doing. Correct that and it will be easier to help.

Comment: I did realise that there were formatting issues after i posted my question. I am new to this and will try to rectify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is provided, it looks as if you added a method/function inside `viewWillAppear`. If that is not a typing mistake and you did indeed set your code up like that, modifying your code to look like this will get it to work:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Choose an option!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    //Create and add the Cancel action
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
        //Just dismiss the action sheet
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Basically, do not have a method inside `viewWillAppear` but also move your action sheet display code to `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`